# Online touch typing app that focuses on eliminating typos?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am trying to find an app I once saw which teaches you how to touch type and focuses on eliminating typos.

I remember that one of the unique aspects of the program was that it said to not use the backspace key since then you become reliant on it (or something similar to that).

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: You can practice your speed afterwards here: http://speedtest.10-fast-fingers.com

Answer (score 1):

[Typingweb](http://www.typingweb.com/) - Probably not the exact one you are looking for, but the best one I've used.

Answer (score 0):

This might help
http://www.sense-lang.org/typing/tutor/index.php?lang=EN

Comment: Nope that was not it, thanks for the suggestion though.